# simple xml getName does not work

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I try to get the element name of the xml. I use getName() function. But I do not know why it always goes wrong, it gets error on that page.

```
    $xml=filePath::$xml; //guide to the xml file

    //use simple xml to get the attributes

        $xmldoc=simplexml_load_file($xml);


        //get the children
        foreach($xmldoc->children() as $child) {

            foreach($child->attributes() as $a=>$b) {
              echo $b;//this statement works correctly

            }
            echo $child->getName();//this statement does not work, and it leads to the error.

        }
```

why?

The xml file like:
root
  collection id="new1"
  slash collection
  collection id="new2"
  slash collection
slash root

The correctly output should be: new1 collection new2 collection. But the "collection" cannot be print out.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `$child->getName()`?

Comment: I think it would be useful to see the XML, or at least a sample, that leads to this error.

Comment: I think you are forgeting something (maybe your PHP syntax or using not valid XML) also I made you 2 examples, check my post.

Comment: if I use $child->attribute() to get the attributes of the elment, it works. But when I try $child->getName() to get element name/node name, it wont work. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following, I made you two examples about how to load, get and print data from local and remote XML and maybe you forgot something.

Also will be good for you to check your XML document syntax if it is 100% correct.

You can use this tool to validate your XML:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

---

**Loading local XML, get and print data:**

```
<?php

// xml example with namespaces
$xml = '<market 
xmlns:m="http://mymarket.com/">
<m:fruit>
  <m:type>
    <m:name from="US">Apples</m:name>
    <m:name>Bananas</m:name>
  </m:type>
  <m:sell>
    <m:date>2012-06-24</m:date>
  </m:sell>
</m:fruit>
</market>';

// load the xml
$elems = simplexml_load_string($xml);

// evaluate if not null
if($elems != null){

    // declare the namespaces
    $ns = array(
      'm' => "http://mymarket.com/"
    );

    // for each td inside tr
    foreach ($elems->children($ns['m'])->fruit->type->name as $item) {
        echo $item->attributes()->from;
        echo ',';
        echo $item;
    }

    // get just an element without using loop
    echo ','.$elems->children($ns['m'])->fruit->sell->date;

    // final output is: US,Apples,Bananas,2012-06-24 
}

?>
```

**Loading remote XML, get and print data:**

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.mymarket.com/products.xml";

// evaluate if not null
if(getXml($url) != null){

    // declare the namespaces
    $ns = array(
      'm' => "http://mymarket.com/"
    );

    // for each td inside tr
    foreach ($elems->children($ns['m'])->fruit->type->name as $item) {
        echo $item->attributes()->from;
        echo ',';
        echo $item;
    }

    // get just an element without using loop
    echo ','.$elems->children($ns['m'])->fruit->sell->date;

    // final output is: US,Apples,Bananas,2012-06-24 
}

function getXml($url)
{
    $xml = @file_get_contents($url);
    // If page not found and server has a 404 error redirection, use strpos to look through the $xml
    if($xml == false || strpos($xml,'404') == true){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        $elems = simplexml_load_string($xml);
        return $elems;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: if I use $child->attribute() to get the attributes of the elment, it works. But when I try $child->getName() to get element name/node name, it wont work. Why?

Comment: Try to use your XML document with the examples I made and look if it works (It is supposed to work, I tested) if doesn't work, validate your XML and look if it is Ok, I also gave you a tool

Comment: My other idea is to use this simple example using php getname() function from XML and if doesnt work then your XML is corrupt, check this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_getname.asp

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the xml document is valid?

Does the script get past

```
 if($xmldoc!=null)
     {
```

It may be declaring $xmldoc null because the document isnt valid.